# Assign the dynamic url to the variable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to assign the dynamic url to the variable. Here is the sample link

http://xyz.com/Screen.aspx?RID=1234&abc=1

http://xyz.com/Screen.aspx?RID=5678&abc=1

Looking at the url, 1234 and 5678 is dynamic and rest of the other is static. So how I can make this url and assign it to the variable.

Comment: Do you understand what you ask?

Comment: This url is been used in front end... 'http://xyz.com/Screen.aspx?RID=' is static and '1234' is dynamic and also '&abc=1' is static. So now I want to develop the link and want to assign it to the variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select @variablename = 'http://xyz.com/Screen.aspx?RID=' 
  + convert(varchar,@someothervar or column_name) + '&abc=1'
```